# Tomcat won't start (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, batch-file, tomcat, classpath, pentaho

I´m trying to launch an application (pentaho business intelligence server) but the .bat file won´t run. It doesn´t throw any error or anything, the command prompt pops up and then disappears right after. Then I figured out that it´s tomcat that isn´t running, but no error is being logged in the tomcat logs folder.

This is what shows in the command prompt when I start the bat file (I had to add a pause to see where it goes before exiting)

[image]

I also run the catalina.bat file and I also could see that the last thing it tried to run was this CLASSPATH, and seems like it was trying to open this tomcat-juli.jar and bootstrap.jar, but is not working somehow.

I´m not really familiar with any of this, so I´m not sure if this is normal, could you point me to the right direction on how to solve this?

EDIT 1. I was suggested to add the code of the bat file in question, here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /D %~dp0
cscript promptuser.js //nologo //e:jscript
rem errorlevel 0 means user chose "no"
if %errorlevel%==0 goto quit
echo WScript.Quit(1); > promptuser.js

call set-pentaho-env.bat "%~dp0jre"

cd tomcat\bin
set CATALINA_HOME=%~dp0tomcat

SET BITS=64
SET DI_HOME="%~dp0pentaho-solutions\system\kettle"

set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms2048m -Xmx6144m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -DDI_HOME=%DI_HOME%

rem Make sure we set the appropriate variable so Tomcat can start (e.g. JAVA_HOME iff. _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME points to a JDK)
if not exist "%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%\bin\jdb.exe" goto noJdk
if not exist "%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJdk
set JAVA_HOME=%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%
set JRE_HOME=
goto start

:noJdk
rem If no JDK found at %_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME% unset JAVA_HOME and set JRE_HOME so Tomcat doesn't misinterpret JAVA_HOME == JDK_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=
set JRE_HOME=%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%

:start
call startup
:quit
endlocal
pause
```

EDIT 2. After some research I'm sure the problem is that tomcat doesn't start, changing the title of the question.

Things that I've already tried:

- Changing the port from 8080 to 8081.
- Setting  _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME environment.
- Opening tomcat (startup.bat) and catalina.bat from the command prompt, it just tells me it runs it but exits after CLASSPATH (exactly the same as the screenshot provided).
- Checking the logs file in tomcat, it's empty

Comment: Not an expert here, but it would be useful to see the code in .bat so maybe someone is able to tell you what’s wrong

Comment: Are you sure it isn't running?  Tomcat usually creates a new window to run in.

Comment: @stdunbar yes, I´m sure, there is no other window, just this one because I added the pause, otherwise it would just disappear right after popping up

Comment: `startup.bat` starts Tomcat in the background and exits immediately. If Tomcat really doesn't start (`http://localhost:8080` does not respond), you need to look into the logs (in `pentaho-server/tomcat/logs`).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz , yes, if I start startup.bat it exits immediately, but when I check pentaho-server/tomcat/logs the folder is empty.

I've also used PostgreSQL pgadmin in localhost:8080, do you think that might be the problem? I´ve also edited the port to 8081 and tried again (I read somewhere that might help) but still not working

Comment: I now tried opening startup.bat from the command prompt and it said I hadn't set the variable JAVA_HOME, fixed it, and still doesn't work. Tried opening the tomcat startup.bat file and now I see the same as my first screenshot, it just stops after the CLASSPATH

Comment: for sure if port 8080 is already in use, it wont start. try setting another port by replacing the string "8080" with something else (eg 8090) in tomcat/config/server.xml... then i suggest you to open a command prompt, move to tomcat/bin folder, and run> catalina start

Comment: it look like you need also to set the enviroment variable --> _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME

Comment: @kkk I´ve already tried setting the envioment variable _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME and changing the port to 8081, but still won´t run

Comment: If you want to start Tomcat without detaching it from the terminal, replace `call startup` with `call catalina.bat run`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I already did it, still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work, I uninstalled java 11 and installed java 8 (this version is compatible with pentaho), then I changed the environment _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME to this java 8, that made it work. But now I can only make it work from the tomcat startup.bat and not from the file start-pentaho.bat, so I guess there is still a way to make it work as it was meant to.